# Her or hers or her’s

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Talking about possessive pronoun, which one is correct?

1. Don’t eat Margaret’s pizza, it’s her.
2. Don’t eat Margaret’s pizza, it’s hers.
3. Don’t eat Margaret’s pizza, it’s her’s.

Comment: There are no apostrophes in the possessive pronouns ***yours, his, hers, ours, theirs, its***. That's a really simple "rule", but sadly you'll see that lots of otherwise perfectly well-educated native Anglophones can't seem to grasp it as regards the ***last*** item in that list.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from FumbleFingers' comment,

the pizza is **hers**.

To say that it was **her** would indicate that she had been turned into a pizza rather than being the person to whom it belonged.

PS. I recently, with the approval of the Portuguese snack-bar owner concerned, scratched out the apostrophe in the sign on the toilet door reading: **Customer's only** - that some helpful Briton had contributed. Numerous native English speakers tend to insert an erroneous apostrophe before the **s** when using the plural.

Comment: Even greengrocer's (sic) have to have a holiday ;-) https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-greengrocers-apostrophe-1690826